# No new elements are added to the swift/firebase array

Tags: arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I use a notification system for an app using Firebase. When I like a post, I get a notification in the view, but when I like the same post, the notification changes to a new one, to put it simply, it overwrites, I noticed this while debugging. I don't understand what could be the reason

```
import Firebase
import UIKit

class LikedTweetsNotif: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: LikedTweetsNotif, rhs: LikedTweetsNotif) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    let tweetId = UUID()
    let id: String
    let username: String
    let profileImageUrl: String
    let tweet: String
    let uid: String
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    let caption : String
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date:Date())
        self.tweet = dictionary["tweet"] as? String ?? ""
        self.caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String ?? ""
    }
    
    var timestampString: String {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth, .year]
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue(), to: Date()) ?? ""
    }
    
    
    var detailedTimeStampString: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a  MM/dd/yyyy"
        return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue())
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import ProgressHUD

class NotificationsViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var likedTweetsNotif = [LikedTweetsNotif]()
    @Published var subscribesUserNotif = [SubscribeUserNotification]()


    init() {
        fetchLikedTweetsNotif()
        fetchSubscribesUserNotif()
    }
    
    func fetchLikedTweetsNotif() {
        guard let user = AuthViewModel.shared.user else { return }
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(user.id).collection("notifications-tweets").getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.likedTweetsNotif.append(contentsOf: documents.map({LikedTweetsNotif(dictionary: $0.data()) }).sorted(by: { $0.timestamp.dateValue() > $1.timestamp.dateValue() }))
        }
    }
}
```

LikeButton ViewModel

```
    func likeTweet() {
        let newValue = tweet.likes + 1
        guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
        let tweetLikesRef = COLLECTION_TWEETS.document(tweet.id).collection("tweet-likes")
        let userLikesRef = COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).collection("user-likes")
        
        COLLECTION_TWEETS.document(tweet.id).updateData(["likes": newValue]) { _ in
            tweetLikesRef.document(uid).setData([:]) { _ in
                userLikesRef.document(self.tweet.id).setData([:]) { _ in
                    self.sendNotification(for: self.tweet.uid, caption: self.tweet.caption, tweetId: self.tweet.id)
                    self.didLike = true
                    self.tweetLikes += 1
                    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func sendNotification(for userId: String, caption: String, tweetId: String) {
        guard let users = AuthViewModel.shared.user else { return }
        
//        guard let userCheck = AuthViewModel.shared.user?.isCurrentUser else { return }
        
        
        
        
        if users.id == userId {
            
        } else {
            
            let uid = tweet.uid
            
            let docRef = COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).collection("notifications-tweets").document(tweetId)
            
            let data: [String:Any] = ["uid": users.id,
                                      "tweet" : userId,
                                      "caption": caption,
                                      "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date()),
                                      "username": users.username,
                                      "profileImageUrl": users.profileImageUrl,
                                      "id": docRef.documentID]
            
            docRef.setData(data) { _ in
                print("DEBUG: Succesfully sended notfication")
            }
        }
    }
```